# Collecting survey data with Custom dimensions and metrics in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, survey

I was wondering that is there anything that I should be concerned about when collecting survey data to Analytics?

It is a small 3-4 step survey that has structured questions.
The purpose of this survey it to give better insight on how visitors feel about our site and perhaps to help analyze different contents.

I'm 100 % sure about on which level I should to collect the data: hit, session or user level.

EDIT:
I just noticed that dimensions can only be sent with pageview. If I have survey with three questions it would mean +3 pageview for a single page.
In a long run wouldn't it distort almost all data in collected to analytics?

And secondly, if I were to create a "virtual page" and e.g. separate them into own view then it could fit to all other data at session level but on page/hit level it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to be concerned about is privacy - structured question (yes/no, rating scales etc) should be fine. Do not use text input since users might enter personal data.

For the scope it depends on your use case. I have implemented something like this for a "was this page helpful"-gadget, and that is obviously hit scope since it is supposed to tell me something about the content of that url.

If you want to analyze user reactions to multiple subsequent pageviews you would use session scope. From your question it seems that this is what you  want to do.

User scope assumes that your users can only answer once and not change their minds (it is technically possible to overwrite user scope variables, but conceptually this is something that is set once).

Comment: You just red my mind. I'm collecting same-ish "did you find what you were looking for?". For now I've set the answers to be saved on session level, because on hit level it could be to misleading since I can't know if visitor already found it on previous page. If the plan was on hit level then the whole question or survey should be reformatted and perhaps change the business logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

That all completely depends on what you are collecting. Are you collecting clicks on a forward and back button, then maybe you want to use events and not dimensions. If you're trying to set a goal funnel and see where they drop out (or if they complete), then you'd likely want to set a destination Goal and then setup a conversion funnel for that goal if it's multiple steps (pages). Then you can see at which step they would drop out, etc... -- As far as dimensions, I'm not sure what "dimensions" you would want to set strictly for a survey...without knowing what information you're trying to collect, it's impossible to say whether it should be hit, session, or user.